# global eventFilter doesn't catch event for target in QThread in Qt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, eventfilter

I was experimenting around with eventFilters, when I found out about a global-event-filter in the [qt-articel "The Event System"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters), which says:

> *It is also possible to filter all events for the entire application, by installing an event filter on the QApplication or QCoreApplication object.*

I tried with a small script and it worked just fine:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class EventReceiver(QObject):
    def event(self, event:QEvent):
        if event.type() == customType:  # it's allways 65530 :/
            print(f'received event: {event.type()}')#
            # thread.quit()
            return True
        return super().event(event)

class GlobalFilter(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, object:QObject, event:QEvent):
        if event.type() == customType:
            print(f'catched event: {event.type()}')
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    customType = QEvent.registerEventType()

    receiver = EventReceiver()
    filter = GlobalFilter()
    # thread = QThread()
    # receiver.moveToThread(thread)
    # filter.moveToThread(thread)
    # thread.start()
    app.installEventFilter(filter)

    app.postEvent(receiver, QEvent(customType))
    app.exec()
    del receiver, filter, app,  # thread
```

which outputs: `catched event: 65530 received event: 65530` just as expected

Then I moved the receiver-object (and the filter) to an other thread:

```
...
thread = QThread()
receiver.moveToThread(thread)
filter.moveToThread(thread)
thread.start()
...
```

output: `received event: 65530` (no catch)

Not moving the filter to the other thread leads to the same (incomplete) output, but as said in [`QObject::installEventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter):

> *Note that the filtering object must be in the same thread as this object. If filterObj is in a different thread, this function does nothing.*

The event-filter works fine when directly installing on the receiver, but not as a global one. What am I missing here?

---

If someone needs a **workaround:** 
subclassing the QApplication, to [overwrite the the notify()-function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify) works fine to catch the event:

```
class NotifyApplication (QApplication):
    def notify(self, object:QObject, event:QEvent):
        if event.type() == customType:
            print(f'catched event: {event.type()}')
        return super().notify(object, event)

app = NotifyApplication([]) 
...
```

Still this doesn't helped me understand how the global-event-filter should work. Any Insight welcome :)

Comment: what I can think of is that you create an eventFilter for each thread that is handled by a global QObject.

Comment: Why do you want to use eventfilter? What is your main objective?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I don't have any goal yet. I was just trying around, to maybe use more events instead of signals/slots for my custom classes. But their is no use-case for this yet.